# Labelling the corners of a 3-d box with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a rectangular prism in Tikz.  I'd like to label the corners of the box, but I'm having trouble doing so.  Here's the code to generate the box:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\cubex}{4}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\cubey}{5}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\cubez}{3}
\draw (0,0,0) -- ++(-\cubex,0,0) -- ++(0,-\cubey,0) -- ++(\cubex,0,0) -- cycle;
\draw (0,0,0) -- ++(0,0,-\cubez) -- ++(0,-\cubey,0) -- ++(0,0,\cubez) -- cycle;
\draw (0,0,0) -- ++(-\cubex,0,0) -- ++(0,0,-\cubez) -- ++(\cubex,0,0) -- cycle;
\draw[dashed] (-\cubex,0,-\cubez) -- ++(0,-\cubey,0);
\draw[dashed] (-\cubex,-\cubey,-\cubez) -- node[below]{A} (-\cubex,-\cubey,0);
\draw[dashed] (-\cubex,-\cubey,-\cubez) -- (0,-\cubey,-\cubez);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I'd like to label each of the corners with a letter A through H.  How could I do this?  Additionally I'd like A to be below the bottom, front, left corner.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\cubex}{4}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\cubey}{5}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\cubez}{3}
\draw   (0,0,0) node[right] {C} 
    -- ++(-\cubex,0,0) node[left]  {B} 
    -- ++(0,-\cubey,0) node[left]  {A} 
    -- ++(\cubex,0,0)  node[right] {D} -- cycle;
\draw   (0,0,0) -- ++(0,0,-\cubez) node[right] {G} 
                -- ++(0,-\cubey,0) node[right] {H} -- ++(0,0,\cubez);
\draw   (0,0,0) -- ++(-\cubex,0,0) 
                -- ++(0,0,-\cubez) node[left]  {F} -- ++( \cubex,0,0);
\draw[dashed] (-\cubex,0,-\cubez) -- ++(0,-\cubey,0);
\draw[dashed] (-\cubex,-\cubey,-\cubez) node[left]{E} --  (-\cubex,-\cubey,0);
\draw[dashed] (-\cubex,-\cubey,-\cubez)  -- (0,-\cubey,-\cubez);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]